# Is US 5278057 A still in force?

Tags: patent-lifetime, us5278057, us5180873

This is a continuation of patent [EP 0198288 A3](https://www.google.com/patents/EP0198288A3). The last legal event recorded for the continuation patent is an expiration in 2006 due to failure to pay a maintenance fee. Does this mean that the newer patent is expired but the original still stands? How can I find out if the continuation was revived? Would that have been recorded in the list of legal events?

Answer (score 1):

US 5278057 has expired (it would have had no effect past January 2010 even if the maintenance fees were paid, due to the terminal disclaimer). The EP application was never patented.

**Update**

This was the correct answer, but I wanted to add the following additional information about the Legal Events, as well as information on a second grant issued from the same application (also expired). The Effective date for the FP codes is the last date the patent was enforcable (January 11, 2006 and January 19, 2005).

[**US 5278057**](https://www.google.com/patents/US5278057)

```
Feb 24, 1997    FPAY    Fee payment
                        Year of fee payment: 4
Feb  7, 2001    FPAY    Fee payment
                        Year of fee payment: 8
Oct 23, 2001    AS      Assignment
Jul 27, 2005    REMI    Maintenance fee reminder mailed 
Jan 11, 2006    LAPS    Lapse for failure to pay maintenance fees   
Mar  7, 2006    FP      Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee
                        Effective date: 20060111
```

[**US 5,180,873**](https://www.google.com/patents/US5180873)

```
Jun 17, 1985    AS      Assignment  
                        Owner name: ADVANCED GENETIC SCIENCES, INC., 6701 SAN PABLO AV
                        Effective date: 19850531
Jul  5, 1990    AS      Assignment  
                        Owner name: DNA PLANT TECHNOLOGY CORPORATION, A CORP. OF DE, N
                        Effective date: 19890712
Apr 22, 1996    FPAY    Fee payment 
                        Year of fee payment: 4
Apr 28, 2000    FPAY    Fee payment 
                        Year of fee payment: 8
Oct 23, 2001    AS      Assignment  
Aug  4, 2004    REMI    Maintenance fee reminder mailed 
Jan 19, 2005    LAPS    Lapse for failure to pay maintenance fees   
Mar 15, 2005    FP      Expired due to failure to pay maintenance fee   
                        Effective date: 20050119
```